# How to make my vue component easily usable?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using vue3/quasar and I created this component to enter dates
in forms

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-sm">
    <q-input
      v-model="model.date"
      label="Date *"
      lazy-rules
      error-message="Choisissez une date valide"
      :error="!isValidDate"
    >
      <template #append>
        <q-icon name="calendar_month" class="cursor-pointer">
          <q-popup-proxy>
            <q-date
              v-model="model.date"
              :mask="dateMask"
              :locale="myLocale"
              :options="dateOptions"
            />
          </q-popup-proxy>
        </q-icon>
      </template>
    </q-input>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed, watch } from "vue";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { toIsoDate, fromIsoDate, toSlashedDate } from "src/utils";
const emit = defineEmits(["updateclient"]);
import { usePeriodStore } from "src/stores/period";

const { getCurrentPeriod } = storeToRefs(usePeriodStore());
const model = ref({
  date: "",
});
//watch the model to inform the parent (client)
watch(model.value, (newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue);
  emit("updateclient", toIsoDate(newValue.date));
});
const dateOptions = computed(() => {
  let period = getCurrentPeriod.value();
  return function (date) {
    return (
      date >= toSlashedDate(period.start) && date <= toSlashedDate(period.end)
    );
  };
});
const dateMask = "DD/MM/YYYY";

const myLocale = {
  /* starting with Sunday */
  days: "dimanche_lundi_mardi_mercredi_jeudi_vendredi_samedi".split("_"),
  daysShort: "dim._lun._mar._mer._jeu._ven._sam.".split("_"),
  months:
    "janvier_février_mars_avril_mai_juin_juillet_août_septembre_octobre_novembre_décembre".split(
      "_"
    ),
  monthsShort:
    "janv._fevr._mars_avr._mai_Juin_juil._août_sept._oct._nov._déc.".split("_"),
  firstDayOfWeek: 1, // 0-6, 0 - Sunday, 1 Monday, ...
  format24h: true,
  pluralDay: "dias",
};

const isValidDate = computed(() => {
  if (/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(model.value.date)) return true;
  return false;
});
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

in the parent component I use it like this

```
<template>
    ...
    <date-selector @updateclient="updateDate" />
    ....
</template>

<script setup>
    ....
    const myForm=ref{
              ...
              date,
              ...
    }
    function updateDate(newdate){
        myForm.value.date=newDate
    }
```

It works but it has limitations.

First having to add a function updateDate in the parent each time I use the component is a bit tedious. I would prefer to use it with something like

```
<date-selector v-model="myForm.date" />
```

Second, I would have to pass a props to initialize its value when necessary which could be done more easily with v-model.

How can I do this ?